# Which JQuery event to respond to when a div is created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

I have a prettify functions that makes dates in a more readable format but I only want the javascript to run after the page loads and all the dates are queried and loaded from the database. Currently I just have the script called at the bottom of my html page as opposed to the header but this seems like bad design for two reasons:

1. The script should be included in the head of the html as previously stated
2. The dates are created and then later on after the rest of the page loads they are converted to their "pretty" form. This may or may not cause a flicker as the dates are converted from one format to another.

Is there a way to, using Javascript/JQuery to prettify the dates as their divs/elements are created? I am somewhat new to JQuery so please forgive this possibly newbie question.

Comment: Actually having the script at the bottom is much better. You're page will render faster as it doesn't have to wait to load your script.

Comment: @Felix -- Yes, I might add that it is better because the web browser, upon loading the page, first renders the page and then executes the scripts after nearly all the markup has been passed to the browser and hopefully been rendered. I also think it might be useful if a third party host is taking some time to answer the requeest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you should call your script within this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
... your script here...
});
```

About scripts loaded in the header, you're not totally right, you should read http://headjs.com and maybe use this method to optimize your pages (headJS also provides an "onload" event)